# AVPlayer is not visible in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, ios11

In my app we are using AVPlayer to play a audio file. In iOS 11 Beta versions the audio is playing fine but the player is not visible. its just displaying a black background.
can any one help me to solve this issue?

```
_avpvc = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init]; 
AVPlayerItem *aPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url]; 
_avpvc.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:aPlayerItem]; 
_avpvc.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url]; 
 [self.view  addSubview:self.avpvc.view]; 
self.avpvc.view.frame = self.audioPlayerView.bounds; 
self.avpvc.view.autoresizingMask = 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; 
[self.audioPlayerView addSubview:self.avpvc.view]; 
[self.avpvc didMoveToParentViewController:self]; 
[_avpvc.player play];
```

Comment: Please find the following url but the code is working fine in all other versions except iOS 11 http://dpaste.com/3YCSZSS

Comment: whats your URL.

Comment: can you add your code here

Comment: http://dpaste.com/3YCSZSS

Comment: whats your URL u used

Comment: we are downloading mp3 files and saving in document directory. For playing the audio files we are mapping the document directory. The Audio is playing. but the player is not visible. Its not visible only in iOS 11.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153334/discussion-between-srikanth-aravamudan-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your help I fixed it.. The problem because we have to increase the size of the view as iOS 11 designed new layout for AVplayer. Now its working fine

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. I have online and offline content (HLS video). My online contents are playing perfectly. But in the case of offline video playback I am facing above issue. Can you post your answer here? It may help me to solve my issue.

Comment: We have to increase the video view size in storyboard. no specific code required

Answer (score -1):

You need to create your own custom player to serve the purpose.Using UISliders and UIbuttons.By Default you won't get Player UI.